# Нужно убрать первый символ строки

Tags: c++

Есть программа, которая в цикле сравнивает строки, всё в ней работает, но в итоге превышается тайм лимит на 0,001 - 0,007 секунды. Решил с каждой итерацией отсекать первый символ, для ускорения работы цикла, но как это сделать?!
P.S. Длина строки может достигать 100,000 символов.

Код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
std::ofstream cout("output.txt");
std::ifstream cin("input.txt");

int main() {
   char e[100002] , m[100002] , s[100002];
   int l ;
   cin >> e ;
   cin >> m ;
   cin >> s ;
   l = strlen(e);
   for (int i=0; i <= l ;i++) {
   if (strncmp(m,e,i) != 0 || strncmp(s,e,i) != 0 ) {
        if (strncmp(m,e,i) == 0 && strncmp(s,e,i) != 0 ) { cout << "Masha";
            break; }
        if (strncmp(m,e,i) != 0 && strncmp(s,e,i) == 0 ) { cout << "Sasha";
            break; }
        if (strncmp(m,e,i) != 0 && strncmp(s,e,i) != 0 ) { cout << "Draw";
            break; }
        break;
   }
else { continue;}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Не провериться равенство 1 символа в строках.
2. Нужно отсекать постоянно, иначе эффекта не будет.

Comment: Что подразумеваете под отсекать?

Comment: Опишите логику. Нужно найти, у кого строка совпадает и совпадение длиннее?

Comment: Вам нужно преобразовать в compressed radix tree. Тогда всё сведётся к очень быстрому проходу по дереву.

Comment: @0andriy Что это не знаю, но за подсказку спасибо.

Comment: @HasmikGaryakaНужно сравнить строки М и С с эталоном Е, если в строке М ошибка найдена раньше - вывести Саша, если в С раньше - Маша, если ошибка найдена одновременно - Ничья.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно инкрементировать указатели.
m указывает на начало строки, а после m++ уже на второй символ и так далее.
и все время сравнивать 1 символ.
То есть

```
for (int i=0; i < l ;i++) {
   if (m[i]!= e[i] || s[i] != e[i] ) {
        if (m[i]== e[i] && s[i] != e[i] ) { cout << "Masha";
            break; }
        if (m[i]!= e[i] && s[i] == e[i]) { cout << "Sasha";
            break; }
        if (m[i]!= e[i] && s[i] != e[i] ) { cout << "Draw";
            break; }
        break;
   }
//else быть не может    

}
```

Comment: TimeLimit исчез, но теперь решение не всегда верно, иду фиксить, спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Делай сравнение только 1 раз:

```
for (int i=0; i <= l ;i++) 
{
    int m_e_i = strncmp(m,e,i);
    int s_e_i = strncmp(s,e,i);
    if (m_e_i != 0 || s_e_i !=0 ) 
    {
        if (m_e_i == 0 && s_e_i !=) {}
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea! Попробую.

Comment: Не помогло, снизило на 0,001 в пике (

Comment: Это правильно было, но у него постоянно проверяются строки, которые уже проверено, что равны.